# Do I start tor in firefox?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

I do not know if I installed tor correctly. No icon to click on to start it. I have Console open as SU ending line #.

Comment: More info is needed. What method of install did you use? If you just installed the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) all that is necessary is to launch the Tor Browser and it will connect you to the Tor network. Downloading and installing the Tor Browser is the recommended method for those that are new to Tor. If you want to verify that you are connected to the Tor network type any URL ending in .onion into the address bar. If it resolves the site then you are good to go. Here's a link to the [Deep Dot Web Site](http://DeepDot35Wvmeyd5.onion) using their .on

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`Tor Browser`](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en), as the [Tor Project FAQ states](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#TBBOtherBrowser):

> In short, using any browser besides Tor Browser with Tor is a really bad idea.
>
> Our efforts to work with the Chrome team to [add missing APIs](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/google-chrome-incognito-mode-tor-and-fingerprinting) were unsuccessful, unfortunately. Currently, it is impossible to use other browsers and get the same level of protections as when using the Tor Browser.

`Tor Browser` or `Tor` running purely as a client do not require "su" or root privileges, and infact you should avoid running *anything* as root (or a privileged user) that doesn't explicitly require it.

Follow the guide on the `Tor Browser` link above, or use Micah's [`torbrowser-launcher`](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher) if it's available, or use [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/). You should avoid trying to engineer your own solution.